# How to create a file upload button using css3 flexbox and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, jquery-file-upload

**Hello
I want to create a multi-select file upload button on website using flexbox css3 html5 and jquery. please help.
thanks in advance.**

Also I want to style differently the choose file button and no file selected text

```css
.btn:link,
.btn:visited{
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.fileToUpload:link,
.fileToUpload:visited,
input[type=file]
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    padding:10px; 
    border: 1px solid #96a9ec;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}


.btn:hover,
.btn:active
 {
    background-color: #2622de;
}

input[type=file]:hover,
input[type=file]:active {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<form action="upload.js" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="btn fileToUpload" >
                        
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `action="upload.js"`?? really?

Comment: and what's the relation to php?

Comment: Use <input> tag 'multiple' attribute

Comment: May be this will help. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can I make a upload.js file to uploading it to server. that's why upload.js. may be I am wrong. any suggestions and corrections to the code is welcome as I am a newbie.

Comment: Fffttt.. check my answer,

Answer (score 1):

i can't to write code for you, you must learing for this.
i just give you simple information for design upload button, in that input, you can't edit because not all browser design same type for upload button, we know HTML is code for browser, and so all browsers can't same type button style, you make one by you self.

you can try this :

```css
input[type=file]{
  display:none;
}

.uploader{
  width:200px;
  display: block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.uploader div{
  background-color:skyblue;
   position:relative;
   width:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input id='upload' type='file' /><label class='uploader' for='upload' ><div>Upload</div></label>
```

the point is you must hidden true button, and use a label tag.